# Play QSound from a resource file?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm trying to load a QSound file from a qrc file but I can't find a way to do it. Is it possible?

Something like:

```
sound = QSound(":/audio/my_sound.ogg")
sound.play()
```

Unlike pixmaps, this syntax doesn't work for audio.

I'll be using pyinstaller to package the scripts and it would be useful if there was a way to include the sound files in the exe as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you can play an ogg file...on my system I get a console error with the ogg file...so also with the ogg resource

```
        QSound.play("my_sound.ogg") # Error decoding source file:my_sound.ogg
        QSound.play(":/audio/my_sound.ogg") # Error decoding source file::/audio/my_sound.ogg
```

Using a wav file works for me, so it verifies QSound can indeed play from a resource.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QFile
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound

import resources # compiled via: pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    # QSound.play("test.wav")  # Plays fine

    # Using a wav file in the resource as follows gives the following results
    # <!DOCTYPE RCC>
    # <RCC version="1.0">
    #     <qresource prefix="audio">
    #         <file>test.wav</file>
    #     </qresource>
    # </RCC>
    QSound.play(":/audio/test.wav")  # Plays fine

    sound = QSound(":/audio/test.wav")
    sound.play()  # Plays fine

    QSound(":/audio/test.wav").play()  # no sound...no error

    # QFile.copy(":/audio/my_sound.ogg", "temp.ogg")  # Could also copy to a local file to make sure was found in resource
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the problem was really the file format. I also tried converting to mp3 with audacity and the result was the same as the ogg format, no sound and no error. It supports unsigned 8bit and signed 16/32bit PCM but other methods of wav encoding didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of qsound but i know many sound player modules such as pygame,playsound etc you can see the syntax  in there sites they support play, stop, pause and much more